# simple url rewriting problem

Tags: iis, iis-7, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I have an existing website where i have urls like:

```
/application/index/fuseaction/home.uebersicht/a/44/b/45/web/xyz.htm
```

I now want to redirect to:

```
/xyz.html
```

what it tried is

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www\.)?mysite.coml$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} application/index\.cfm.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteMap docmap_301 txt: mapping301.txt
RewriteRule ^/application/index.\cfm/(.*)\.htm ${docmap_301:$1} [NC,L,NS]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an inbound rule then this should work for you:

```
Rewrite Engine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/((.+).htm) $2l [NC,R=302]
```

I'm assuming that the missing `l` from the long url in your example was intentional.